# OpenAI Chat completion, need response in list format instead of string for a travel itinerary

Tags: python, openai-api, chatgpt-api

I am using the following python code to create a travel itinerary :

```
  prompt = (f"Create a detailed travel itinerary from {start_date} to {end_date} spanning {num_days} days for {num_adults} adults "
            f"This will be a round trip from {origin_city} to {destination_city}. Starting from {src_airport_departure} at {departure_flight_date_part1} and arriving on {dest_airport_departure} at {arrival_flight_date_part1}. And then the return flights goes from {src_airport_arrival} at {departure_flight_date_part2} to {dest_airport_arrival} at {arrival_flight_date_part2}"
            f"This flight costs {flight_cost}"
            f"For each day, please suggest activities in {destination_city}"
            f"Preferred activities include: {', '.join(activities)}."
            f"And the trip should definitely include: {trip_must_have}."
            f" I'd like this in a list format, excluding all unnecessary data. and can you always start the itinerary with 'Here is your travel itinerary:\n\n'"
            )


    # Get the model's response
    response = openai.ChatCompletion.create(
    model="gpt-3.5-turbo",
    messages=[
        {"role": "system", "content": "You are a helpful assistant that creates travel itineraries."},
        {"role": "user", "content": prompt}
    ]
)
 
    return response['choices'][0]['message']['content'].strip()
```

I have used different prompts to try to get the response in a list format, where each list element should be a single day from the itinerary. But it keeps giving the response in string format.

Currently i have to use this code in Vue to split the data into different days, but the main issue being that it gives a new format on almost each run :

```
   parseItinerary(text) {
    // Extract main itinerary content and ignore the preamble and postamble
    const mainContent = text.split("Here is your travel itinerary:")[1].split("\nPlease note")[0];

    // Split content by day
    const daySplit = mainContent.split("\n\n");
    const days = [];

    // Process each day
    daySplit.forEach(dayText => {
        if (!dayText) return; // Skip empty strings

        // Extract heading and details
        const headingEnd = dayText.indexOf(':');
        const heading = dayText.split('\n')[0]
        const detailsRaw = dayText.substring(headingEnd + 1).split('\n-').slice(1);
        const details = detailsRaw.map(d => d.trim()).filter(Boolean);

        // Push to days array
        days.push({
            heading: `${heading}`,
            show: false,
            details
        });
    });

    return days;
}
```

My question is that, How can i instruct chat completion to give data in list format, something like this :

response = [
{
heading : Day 1, 2023-10-11 :
description : ......
},
{
heading  : Day 2 ,
......
}
]